# How to send server side encryption customer keys while uploading an object to S3 using a POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, amazon-s3, aes

I have been trying to upload a file to a pre-signed AWS-S3 POST URL that my server generates. During the upload I want the file to be encrypted by a key provided by my user.
These is the info I have been asked to send along with the request:
[When you use SSE-C, you must provide encryption key information using the following request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07qO9.png)

My key is: TEST123
I used online generators to generate the following:
The base64 encoding of the key is: VEVTVDEyMw==
The MD5 hash of the key is: 22b75d6007e06f4a959d1b1d69b4c4bd
The base64 encoding of the md5 hash of the key is: MjJiNzVkNjAwN2UwNmY0YTk1OWQxYjFkNjliNGM0YmQ=

Here's the request I sent to the pre-signed URL:
[Screenshot of the Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4JnJ.png)

I get the following response:
[Screenshot of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2mHg.png)

I couldn't figure out how is the hash not matching. I tried to reverify multiple times but still arrive at the same response. How do I do this?

The upload file should be encrypted by a key provided by my user. That is server-side encryption with customer-provided keys (SSE-C).

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.  That said your base64 string is an encoding of the hexadecimal representation of the hash, not the hash itself.  It should be `IrddYAfgb0qVnRsdabTEvQ==`

Comment: Thanks. You were right. It was due to my faulty base64 encoding. The hashes match now. But I get this error response: 
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>The secret key was invalid for the specified algorithm.</Message>
The key is TEST123.
X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption-Customer-Algorithm:AES256
X-Amz-Server-Side-Encryption-Customer-Key:VEVTVDEyMw==
x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5:IrddYAfgb0qVnRsdabTEvQ==

Comment: I fixed it. Turns out, before base64 encoding my I need to create a buffer like so: const buff = Buffer.from(32, "KEY); const base64 = buff.toString("base64").